# How to make Android Buttons show animation on itself when clicked

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a Button that will play a animation-list when pressed.

I have made a animation.xml shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/one" android:duration="500" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/two" android:duration="500" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/three" android:duration="500" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/four" android:duration="500" />
</animation-list>
```

Also for the onClick function:

```
b_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) b_button.getBackground();
frameAnimation.setOneShot(true);
frameAnimation.start();
```

When I press the button, the animation would be played, however, for just once, after when I press it the second time, it will not play. Furthermore, how do I change the button back to it's original state? Meaning the grey default look of the button.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if (frameAnimation.isRunning()) {
      frameAnimation.stop();
  } else {
      frameAnimation.stop();
      frameAnimation.start();
  }
```

try is this works(with OneShot and without OneShot)? The animation will stop at last frame, so you can add a  in xml which drawable is the grey default look
thx :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried to add this after .start(), but what happens is that it would stop at the first frame. Do you know how to call the android own set of drawable grey default look buttons? Thanks