# Add animation in the button

Tags: c#, animation, mono, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I want to create animation on the button.
Button has its image. When clicking on the button should work animated image. Once the animation is complete - show previous image.

Something like the following algorithm:

> **Closed shutter > Click > PLAY ANIMATED SHUTTER > Show image**

I already have ready animation "Animation.gif". It needs to be run when you click on the button.

How can this be organized?
thank you

Comment: you want all this animation to be done on the button itself is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to port something like this to Mono for Android - [How to make Android Buttons show animation on itself when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921745/how-to-make-android-buttons-show-animation-on-itself-when-clicked)

I would probably tackle this first by getting the animation working, and then second by building a custom view that wrapped the animation and the button together - and exposed a single Click event which could be used by MvvmCross for binding.

It's also worth looking around for blog posts and other questions about 'animating buttons in Android' - e.g. one of the first hits for me was http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/apply-animation-on-button.html - most of these will be Xml and Java and should port very quickly to Mono for Android

Comment: Sorry. I did not elaborate. I already have ready animation "Animation.gif". It needs to be run when you click on the button.

Comment: animated gifs are technology built for the 1990s - you can display them in Android using video views, but I'm not going to advise that. You'll need to work on proper animations - or you'll need to drop MonoDroid/Java and work with an HTML UI like PhoneGap instead!

Comment: Try the XML - it's nice - even web devs don't use animated gifs any more.